# Parameter Field current value exception was Unhandled

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm having a problem in my program that when i click the print button it always show up this error [Sample error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV8Qc.png) and i don't know what to do now.
this is the code, this is my parameters [sample parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZeDd.png)

```
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    CrystalReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton = False

    For Each ctrl As Control In CrystalReportViewer1.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Windows.Forms.ToolStrip Then
            Dim btnNew As New ToolStripButton
            btnNew.Text = "PRINT"
            btnNew.ToolTipText = "Print Reciept"
            CType(ctrl, ToolStrip).Items.Insert(0, btnNew)

            AddHandler btnNew.Click, AddressOf printClick
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub printClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim PrintDialog As New PrintDialog

    If PrintDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        CrystalReport11.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrintDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
        CrystalReport11.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0) 'this is where the error coming up'
        Transact()
    End If
End Sub

   Private Sub btnSlip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSlip.Click


    Dim reportDocument As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    reportDocument = New CrystalReport1
    reportDocument.Refresh()
    reportDocument.SetDataSource(dt)
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, ComboBox2.Text)
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue(1, TextBox1.Text)
    Form2.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument
    Form2.ShowDialog()
    Form2.Dispose()
    Form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

End Sub
```

Comment: See how there's a link on that Exception Assistant window that says "View Details"?  Don't you think that viewing any details available would always be a good idea when something unexpected occurs?

Comment: So you have shown that your report has two parameters: EmployeeName and PaymentID.  Have you provided those values to the report?  I'm not seeing anything in the code that indicates that you have but perhaps it's done elsewhere or through the UI.

Comment: @jmcilhinney (i just edited the code) , yes the values are provided in the paremeter but i still dont understand why its still missing.